# What (kind of body) is TV Licensing, and how do they select people to send their scary mailings to?

Tags: england-and-wales, consumer-protection, spam

Is the body a governmental department? Is it established or commissioned by any legislation in particular? What is its mandated function and mode of function? How does it select what addresses to send its lovely nonsense to, what addresses to skip over?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked for TV Licensing for 9 years. They have two databases: The Post Office Address File (PAF, which they subscribe to for a fee) and their own database of licenced (UK spelling) addresses. They run a periodic compare, and write to the ones that are on the PAF but not the TVL. At the time, there were 27 million households on the PAF, and 24 million on the TVL. Data from elsewhere showed that 97% of UK households had TVs, so there was a gap to be closed (around 3 million) which represented extra revenue for the BBC, and they got some of that kicked back as an incentive. The IT infrastructure was ancient (they still had a DEC VAX) and there were anomalies, e.g. letters were sent to places like "Water Tank" and "Railway Signal Box", plus houses were demolished, new ones built, etc.

Also, TV dealers were obliged by law to notify TVL of the names and addresses of people buying or renting TVs, VCRs, etc, but no legal obligation on the buyer to provide their correct address, or any at all.

It is no more illegal to send letters to addresses asking if a TV licence is needed, than it is to send them asking if a credit card is wanted, or begging for a donation to a charity. The letters were carefully worded to avoid any accusation of wrongdoing.

It may be useful to remember that the funding model for the BBC was established nearly 100 years ago, in 1923, when a 'Radio Licence' was required to operate a broadcast radio receiver. These were expensive items, and usually bought from retailers, who could be obliged to notify the licensing authority of purchasers' names and addresses. By the time that licence was abolished, in 1971, radio sets were so cheap and ubiquitous that the scheme was unworkable. The same thing is happening with TVs. Where I live, not a rich suburb, people routinely give away 5 to 7 year old smart or non-smart TVs for nothing, or put them out for trash collection. I can get a USB TV tuner stick for around the equivalent of $15 that would turn my tablet, PC, or Raspberry Pi into a fully functioning TV.

The UK parliament is examining a number of alternative funding models, some of which involve transferring the burden to general taxation.

[HOUSE OF LORDS Communications and Digital Committee 1st Report of Session 2022–23 Licence to change: BBC future funding](https://committees.parliament.uk/publications/23091/documents/169130/default/#:%7E:text=The%20BBC%27s%20main%20source%20of,other%2C%20non-public%20means.)

Note for international readers: in the UK, 'licence' is the noun, and 'license' the verb.

Comment: Very interesting! If you say they were so carefully worded then the answer to the most troublesome part of the question - that as to the threatening and intimidating tone - would seem apparent, but I continue to wonder what the legal department's reasoning in so confidently clearing the copy that goes out actually is. It seems clearly intended to cause harassment alarm and distress, that being its entire apparent strategy.

Comment: Can you offer any illumination on how they reasoned it is so immune to such accusations as of harassment?

Comment: @JosephP. There's more than enough scope within the harassment legislation to exempt their basic approach, and the letters are couched in conditional and/or theatrical language.  They don't 'accuse'. They say things like 'if an enforcement officer finds you are watching TV illegally...'.

Comment: @JosephP. Please don't misunderstand me. I am not a fan of TV Licensing, and especially not a fan of Capita Plc. I do understand that the BBC must be funded somehow.

Comment: I also think that if you prepared a Venn diagram showing circles for whackos who are against speed limits, who send turds in packets to TV Licensing, who think they are 'sovereign citizens', who have plenty of time on their hands, who read the Daily Mail, were enthusiastic Leave voters, etc, there would be considerable overlap.

Answer (score 3):

Much of this is answered at https://www.tvlicensing.co.uk/about/foi-legal-framework-AB16:

> A TV Licence is a legal permission to install or use television
> receiving equipment to watch live on any channel, TV service or
> streaming service, and to use BBC iPlayer*. On any device. This
> applies regardless of which television channels a person receives or
> how those channels are received. The licence fee is not a payment for
> BBC services (or any other television service), although licence fee
> revenue is used to fund the BBC.
>
> The requirement to hold a TV Licence and to pay a fee for it is
> mandated by law under the Communications Act 2003 and the
> Communications (Television Licensing) Regulations 2004 (as amended).
> It is an offence under section 363 of the Communications Act 2003 to
> watch live on any channel, TV service or streaming service, or use BBC
> iPlayer* on any device, without a valid TV Licence.
>
> Section 365 of that Act requires a person to whom a TV Licence is
> issued must pay a fee to the BBC. The amount of this fee and the ways
> it can be paid (as a lump sum or in instalments) is set out in the
> Communications (Television Licensing) Regulations 2004 (as amended).
>
> Since 1991, the BBC, in its role as the relevant licensing authority,
> has been responsible for collecting and enforcing the TV Licence fee.
> The BBC contracts companies to do this work under the BBC trade mark
> ‘TV Licensing’. The BBC (and contractors acting on its behalf) must
> comply with the law in collecting and enforcing the licence fee. The
> BBC Charter further requires the BBC Board to ensure that these
> arrangements are appropriate, proportionate and efficient.

So to your questions:

*Is the body a governmental department?*

No, it consists of private companies or individuals who are under contract to the BBC.

*Is it established or commissioned by any legislation in particular?*

Not per se, but the legislation mentioned above empowers the BBC to collect the fee, and the BBC delegates this function to the TV Licensing contractors.

*What is its mandated function and mode of function?*

To collect legally mandated television license fees.  It does so by various means, some of which are explained [here](https://www.tvlicensing.co.uk/about/our-roles-and-responsibilities-AB3).

> Typically we'll send a number of letters to remind occupants of the importance of being properly licensed. Then we’ll try to contact them by phone. If there’s still no response, we may send a visiting officer to see if there's any TV receiving equipment on the premises. Visits can result in evaders being caught. On average over 1,000 evaders are caught daily.
>
> Detection equipment will only be used if other less intrusive and more cost effective routes have been exhausted.

*How does it select what addresses to send its [letters] to, what addresses to skip over?*

This does not appear to be prescribed by law, so presumably it is up to the discretion and internal policies of TV Licensing and/or the BBC.  That makes it beyond the scope of this site.

However, a reasonable guess would be that they send letters to all households that have neither paid a license fee nor been established as not needing one.  The letter you posted on your other question states that you can go to https://www.tvlicensing.co.uk/noTV to declare that you don't need a license.  I would assume that if your declaration is accepted, they will stop sending letters.

Comment: Isn't this system then uncharacteristically both stupid and ridiculous? Ridiculous because it is a legally empowered enforcement authority adopting an attitude of guilty into established innocent, and stupid because all one need do to avoid enforcement seems very likely to be to inform them to stop their mailings which seems like it might very well also prevent any enforcement visits? So any actual evader could also easily do that?

Comment: On the ridiculous note isn't that opposite to the principle that is used to police criminal offences in the UK, that there is a presumption of innocence and one generally has a basic right not to be arbitrarily visited in one's home and treated as a suspect of a crime without just and reasonable cause for suspicion?

Comment: @JosephP.: Opinions about the law are off topic; see [Politics.SE] for that.  Can you frame a question that does not call for a value judgment?

Comment: @JosephP.: Innocence is presumed at trial.  AFAIK the authorities do not need any particular cause for suspicion in order to *investigate* a possible violation, only to *arrest*.  The TV License inspectors can come to your house just like any of your neighbors can.  You do not have to let them in unless they have a warrant, which they can get from a JP / magistrate under Section 366 only upon "reasonable grounds for believing" that an offense has been committed.

Comment: @JosephP.: Note that declaring No License Needed does not automatically mean they will believe you.  See the [policy document](https://www.tvlicensing.co.uk/ss/Satellite?blobcol=urldata&blobheadername1=content-type&blobheadervalue1=application%2Fpdf&blobkey=id&blobtable=MungoBlobs&blobwhere=1370006620212&ssbinary=true) for how they treat these claims.  If anything I would guess that such a declaration makes an enforcement visit *more* likely than otherwise.

Comment: Section 363 provides an exemption (no license needed) in the case that you are a television receiver dealer or repairman, as long as your use of such devices is soley to install them, to demonstrate their use, to test them, or to repair them.

Comment: @NateEldredge " If anything I would guess that such a declaration makes an enforcement visit more likely than otherwise." - from personal experience, whenever I (truthfully) responded no licence needed they left me alone for some time. I did however promptly respond to the initial letter, not the Nth letter after ignoring them.